# Moving nodes from dev to production (a simple use case)

Tags: features

I want to use the **backup_migrate** module to move some nodes from dev to production (production is still off-line). But the node is split over so many tables...and I also added custom fields (image field) to the node. How do I use backup_migrate module to move the tables? How do I know which tables to move? Should I just move the entire db? then what would be the point of using features to export my configuration? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

From my experience, I use [Node Export](http://drupal.org/project/node_export) to export some nodes and import in other Drupal site (same versions). To export/import a node, the respective Content type must have been created with his respective fields.

Also, this page [Comparison of Content and User Import and Export Modules](http://groups.drupal.org/node/21338) have information about some import/export modules alternatives (also I suggest see comments). Could be suitable for your needs.

I hope information be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the [Deploy](http://drupal.org/project/deploy) module.  It uses webservices for moving content from one Drupal instance to another (ie dev to prod).  The module takes a little bit of effort to setup, but once done it works well.

Deploy is smart enough to take the dependencies with it too, so you only have to specify the nodes to deploy.  Another nice feature of deploy is that you can deploy changes to a live site without wiping out the existing data.

**Note** Deploy for D7 isn't ready for production use, but the D6 version worked well last time I played with it.

Answer (score 0):

Features are meant to move configuration from one db to another (like content types, comment settings, field definitions, etc). Backup_migrate is for moving your whole database from staging to prod with content. it's your best bet for moving nodes from one DB to another.